# BoundingBox pixel coordinates for OSM

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I have the lat/lon for the two BoundingBox corners
and I need to get the "Projection.toPixels()" for those two
points for use with OpenStreetMap.

I already have the basic functions, like getting the Tile
numbers for a lat/lon location, and given a lat/lon in a Tile
getting the X and Y pixels, but I can't find any code that
will help solve my BoundingBox problem.

It's a large BoundingBox, and usually, at zoom 8, the Tiles
with the BoundingBox points, are outside the normal display grid of Tiles
for the display, so the point on the "left" is something like X: -169 Y: -343
and the point on the "right" is like X: 841  Y: 849

So I need a formula, given the lat/lon of the BoundingBox corner
points, and end up with rectangle points like the above pixel offsets.

Currently I'm using Google Maps, and I can get it's version of the
BoundingBox points with "Projection.toPixels()" basically, but I'm
converting to use OpenStreetMap.  They are both based on 256 X 256 tiles,
and use the same Projection, but I don't want to use any Google Maps API calls to do it.

I have seen some Google Maps like source in JavaScript that looks pretty good, but nothing about using BoundingBox.

I already have the display center lat/lon,
zoom level 8, and other needed data, but not the needed formula(s).

The goal is to call an Android draw() function like:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(
    imageBitmap,    // bitmap
    null,           // src rect
    BBRect,         // dest rect
    paint);     // paint
```

I'd like to see code that's similar to Java so I can understand it
enough to convert it if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally have it "working".

This isn't the ideal way to do it, but it seems to "work".

The Projection has to take into account the display
size for it to work, for the proper solution.

But I was thinking about it from the point of view
of the grid of tiles it drew to make up the display.

For my display, it used a grid of three columns
and five rows of tiles for each, and you know what the X and Y it drew each at, and you can figure out where the
corner tiles of the BoundingBox from the lat/lon are,
and you can get the X/Y pixel offsets for the lat/lon in each corner tile.

So you can just "extend" the X/Y tile draw points out to the corner tiles, and then adjust for the pixel offsets in each corner tile, and you should have the rectangle points
for the BoundingBox.

My problem was that initially, when I tried to do that,
the image was a good ways off.  I finally realized that
for the Android Canvas drawing coordinates, it used the
top left corner, but for whatever reason, I was thinking that it was from the bottom left, so once I re-calculated,
it finally looked like it drew the image in the right spot.

I'd like to be able to use the Projection, and properly
figure out how to get the toPixels(), but for now I think
this solution will work.